# Apply for a second PhD in US in a related or same field

Tags: phd, graduate-admissions, second-degree

I seriously need advice. I did my first PhD in my home country (Italy) but it came out to be a disaster (no peer-reviewed pubblications, and none of them in my field), no support from my supervisor, no conferences, no academic network. My research interests were completely different from my department's, and I didn't share any methodological approach of my institution. After completing the PhD I had to face mental and health issues so I stopped for a couple of years, then the pandemic started and everything, of course, got it worst.
I want to go back in academia and, simultaneously, go abroad. I know I am not competitive at all in academic market and I really believe no one can offer me a postdoc position. Furthermore I don't even have a library where I live so it's impossible even to do research on my own. I don't have the fundings to go abroad and do research on my own, go to conferences (I'm not affiliated with any institution since three years) and, most of all, I can't do research while a have here a full-time and stressful work.

I was thinking to apply for another PhD in the US, firstly because I always wanted to move over the Atlantic, secondly because I like how American PhD is structured in comparison to Italian PhD.
But I have a few questions:

I know it's not advisable to do a second PhD in the same (or related) field (e.g. I'm interested in aesthetic and philosophy of music, so I could look also for a doctorate in music theory of art theory) but is it even allowed to do that?

Will I considered a low-profile if I have two PhDs?

I was thinking to write to some professor of the departments I'm interested in and ask a sincere opinion on my plan. Is it a good idea?

I really want to do research but now I'm out of the market, no network and no support by any institution.

I feel like I need to start again and do it better.

Comment: You can always ask but I expect you will find it difficult to get a PhD position. Think about it: You have a track-record of being a below-average PhD candidate. Why should someone offer you a position over other applicants who don't have such a track-record? If you can't answer this question, your chances are extremely low.

Comment: Thank you for your kind and sincere answer. I have a low profile because while I started my PhD began to have health problems (I spend the first two years inside a hospital for continuos check ups) and consequently I developed depression. My supervisor didn't help me at all and left be basically alone in my research.  I think I'm a good researcher, in my institution I began doing research at BA, and I was excellent, very high scores and good research seminars. I had a health and mental breakdown and it really crushes me that I don't have a second chance

Comment: Thank you for you kind words. To me more precise I wasn't hospitalized for two years (luckily) but went very often to the hospital for contious check-ups and examinations, I was hospitalized only once, for 8-10 days. Of course it's very stressful tu do a PhD and at the same time being constantly worried about my health. I agree with you that I have to de-emphasize the mental side. Luckily though now I feel much better and I feel I have control again of my life. Furthermore I am very passionate about the topic of my PhD thesis (Philosophy of music).

Comment: (minor English nit-pick observation in case you're interested) *no peer-reviewed pubblications, and none of them in my field* --- This could easily be understood as saying that you have no peer-reviewed publications, and among your (0 number of) peer-reviewed publications there are none in your field, which is a rather odd conclusion to explicitly state. I suspect you meant: "no peer-reviewed publications, and no publications in my field". The problem is the ambiguity with what "them" refers to -- "peer-reviewed publications" or "publications".

Comment: You might like to browse the [tag:second-degree] tag as it has many questions about this kind of situation.  Note that some US institutions (and maybe elsewhere too) do have policies that they do not accept students for PhD study who already have a PhD in that field or a similar one.  There may be a process for an exception to be made, though.

Comment: There are a lot of comments here that probably should be answers.